# Is it crucial for an engineering student to "master" the epsilon-delta definitions of limits?

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

**I know that this is more a discussion than a math question, but I'd like to know**. Computer engineering student here. When studying, I like to go through all of the book's definitions and proofs, and then finish all the exercises. Just did my limits exam. I'd like to do the same thing for the epsilon-delta chapter of Stewart's book, but right now I'm in a crunch for time, and we're starting derivatives. Should I just skip it?

Comment: Asymptotic notations and limits have the very similar definitions - if You would like to deeply understand one, then you'll have deal with another.

Comment: What are you longer range goals -- undergraduate degree only? Masters degree? Ph.D. in computer engineering? Graduate work (Masters and/or Ph.D.) in something else (presumably related)? In particular, do you plan on staying in computer engineering, or is this simply a stepping stone to something else (e.g. computational mathematics, machine learning, rocket scientist, researcher at google, etc.)? The answer greatly depends on what you plan to do later.

Comment: It’s not crucial, but you might as well do it when you have time because it’s not that hard and it does shed some light on the meaning of a limit, and because otherwise you’ll spend the rest of your life feeling intimidated when you hear people talk about epsilon and delta.

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys!

Comment: On a bit of a tangent, the definition of limit/continuity can be cast in a very engineering-oriented way: a function representing some manufacturing process or similar is continuous if no matter how narrow your tolerance for the output of the process is, there exists some corresponding tolerance for the input such that if the input satisfied the input tolerance, then the result of the process will satisfy the required output tolerance.

Comment: You may find my answer here useful:  https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/498/117

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It helps.**

An engineer never has to understand those concepts as well as a mathematician, but they always help. I will answer this specifically for electrical and electronics engineering.

I am an electrical and electronics engineer and I was involved with teaching too. I can safely say they come around quite a few times in the upcoming years. You will see them again for differential equations, for Fourier Transforms, for feedback systems and for information theory, while the last one is usually a grad level course.

What happens is that each time you gave up something and memorise it as it is, it comes back and haunts you next years, so either you have to exert more effort to cover your weaknesses up, or you memorise more stuff as they are. After a certain point, especially if you do something heavily theoretical, you realise you cannot learn anything anymore and memorise whatever is in front of you.

My suggestion: Don't leave too many blank spots in your first year. There will be other stuff that you will give up learning in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

+1 for doing all the exercises. That said, if this
is not in the actual curriculum for your course then the time crunch argument should prevail. Skip it now even though it's in the book.

In the longer run, you might appreciate its elegance and power. The underlying idea is to validate useful  informal everyday limit vocabulary like "approaches" by a formal structure that codifies the idea of "infinitesimally close" using infinitely many increasingly restrictive inequalities.

Come back to $\epsilon-\delta$ when you have time - perhaps when the semester ends. Then if you see it in more advance courses it will be for the second time.

Comment: Thank you! I'll stick to the current flow of topics and chapters and then I'll get back to it when I have more time.

Comment: @Gabriel Personally, I had a lot of trouble understanding the $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of limits. I only understood it after studying the (what is sometimes called) $\epsilon - N$ definition for convergence of a sequence. It is much easier to understand than $\epsilon - \delta$, or at least it was for me.

Answer (score 3):

Depends. I don't think my friends with PhDs in physics know how to do them. I never encountered them in my own physics classes and I'd think the math there was more thorough than in engineering.

That said, there are situations where it could give you and advantage. A [Symmetric Derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative) offers a better way to calculate the numerical derivative than the formal definition, however the S.D. exists in places where the actual derivative does not. There are probability distributions that make intuitive sense to add together that Delta-Epsilon proofs would make you doubt. Finite Element Analysis methods don't always converge, or at least not rapidly and delta-epsilon can tell you when that is.

Understanding delta-epsilon can help you avoid mistakes and will give you an advantage over not understanding them.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.